# How can I make a link undraggable?

Tags: jquery, css

I am using the following four buttons -- [example on Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fTRDm/)

I like the look of these buttons, but I notice when a user clicks, holds-down on a link and moves the cursor away from the link, the links don't act in the same way as buttons.

Instead they appear as draggable objects although there's a circle that appears to show they are not draggable.

This effect seems not to be unique to my code. I see it everywhere and even if you try and click, drag on the "run" button on fiddle you will see the same.

Maybe I'm being fussy here, but I would really like to try and eliminate this strange effect.

Is there any way I can stop this happening. If I place a button on the page, click and drag then nothing happens at all. No circle appears. No shadow image of the link (firefox) appears. This is the kind of effect I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct: http://jsfiddle.net/fTRDm/2/, onmousedown, not onclick.

Comment: Seems like it does the trick but now I notice my effect for active doesn't seem to work. I was hoping to color the background when active. Any ideas with that?